# What can be improved on this Matlab code? and Is it a correct implementation for KNN ?

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I implemented K-Nearest Neighbours algorithm, but my experience using matlab is very few. I need you to check the small portion of code and tell me what can be improved or modified ? and hope it is a correct implementation of the algorithm ?

```
function test_data = knn(test_data, tr_data,k)

numoftestdata = size(test_data,1);
numoftrainingdata = size(tr_data,1);


for sample=1:numoftestdata

   %Step 1: Computing euclidean distance for each testdata
   R = repmat(test_data(sample,:),numoftrainingdata,1) ;
   euclideandistance  = (R(:,1) - tr_data(:,1)).^2;

   %Step 2: compute k nearest neighbors and store them in an array
    [dist position] = sort(euclideandistance,'ascend');
    knearestneighbors=position(1:k);
    knearestdistances=dist(1:k);


    % Step 3 : Voting 
    for i=1:k
        A(i) = tr_data(knearestneighbors(i),2);  
    end

    M = mode(A);

    if (M~=1)
        test_data(sample,2) = mode(A);
    else 
        test_data(sample,2) = tr_data(knearestneighbors(1),2);
    end
end
```

To test it you can use :

- test_data = [6,0; 2,0; 5,0]
- tr_data = [1,1;0,2;3,2; 4,4; 5,3]

Comment: If you are looking for best practices or optimisation advice rather than help with a specific error I would recommend you to post this to the CodeReview site.

Answer (score 0):

I would do following corrections:

1. Step 3: the loop is not efficient, try `A =tr_data(knearestneighbors,2);`
2. The if statement can be simplified

--

```
test_data(sample,2) = mode(A);

if (M==1)
    test_data(sample,2) = tr_data(knearestneighbors(1),2);
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but what do you think about its Correctness ? does it do what `k-nearest neighbors` is supposed to do ?